# Transcluded element clone can't reach scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created this transclude:'element' Atribute directive:

```
<div repeat="5" ng-click="sayNumber(number)">
        This is number {{number}}           
</div>    

app.directive('repeat', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',            
        transclude: 'element',
        link: function (scope,element,attrs,ctrl,transclude) {
            var repeatNum=parseInt(attrs.repeat);

            for(var i=0;i<repeatNum;i++){
                var childScope = scope.$new();                    
                childScope.number = i;
                transclude(childScope, function(clone,cloneScope) {
                    element.parent().append(clone);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Transclude element rendered as expected, but after - doesn't see parent scope, and can't call any of its functions.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3anj78sz/10/

It's also containing transclude:true Element directive, which works as expected, and standard ng-repeat, which functionality I was trying to achieve with transclude:element directive.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after digging for a while I found out, that this problem has occured because of using multiple angular directives on same element, in this case - both "repeat" ang "ng-click".

That won't causes any trouble in cases, when one directive doesn't depend on another, but if so, it may (or may not) lead to situation, when angular will process dependent directive before the one it depends on.
This happens when directives have same priority, and angular process them in alphabetical order.

So, to make example in the question working, all I have to do, is to set higher priority to "repeat" directive than "ng-click" has.
This is the definition object of correct directive:

```
        {
           restrict: 'A',            
           transclude: 'element',
           priority: 1000,
           link: ...
        }
```